# Case statement based in max min dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a columns as `Memnumber, activity type, activity date, activity ID`. One member can have activities after few days. I want to write a case statement that if the activity date is most initial then INITIAL and if activity is most recent then MR and if there is any activity in between these 2 dates then BETWEEN. They need to be grouped by Memnumber and treatment type.

I wrote query as :

```
--MR County Tree
SELECT T0.MEMBERNUMBER,
    T0.ACTIVITYTYPE,
    T1.MR_CY17,
    T1.IN_CY17,
    T0.ACTIVITY_DATE,
    (T0.ACTIVITYID)
FROM DLA_EXTRACT_FINAL T0
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MEMBERNUMBER,
        ACTIVITYTYPE,
        MAX(ACTIVITY_DATE) MR_CY17,
        MIN(ACTIVITY_DATE) IN_CY17
    FROM DLA20_EXTRACT_FINAL
    WHERE to_char(ACTIVITY_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') >= 20170101
        AND to_char(ACTIVITY_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') <= 20171231
    GROUP BY MEMBERNUMBER,
        ACTIVITYTYPE
    ) T1 ON T0.MEMBERNUMBER = T1.MEMBERNUMBER
    AND T0.ACTIVITYTYPE = T1.ACTIVITYTYPE
    AND T0.ACTIVITY_DATE = T1.MR_CY17
--where  T0.ACTIVITYTYPE='MT'
WHERE t0.MEMBERNUMBER = 'M500085268'
GROUP BY T0.MEMBERNUMBER,
    T0.ACTIVITYTYPE,
    T1.MR_CY17,
    T1.IN_CY17,
    T0.ACTIVITYID,
    T0.ACTIVITY_DATE
ORDER BY T0.MEMBERNUMBER,
    T0.ACTIVITYTYPE,
    T1.MR_CY17,
    T1.IN_CY17.
```

Looking for a solution.

Comment: How are *most initial* and *most recent* defined? Highest *Activity_Date* and closest to today?

Comment: I would write exactly the same question as @Parfait , so consider it been asked twice

Answer (score 1):

You want to use window functions. Something like:

```
SELECT T0.MEMBERNUMBER,
    T0.ACTIVITYTYPE,
    T0.ACTIVITY_DATE,
    T0.ACTIVITYID,
    case when row_number() over (partition by T0.MEMBERNUMBER, T0.ACTIVITYTYPE
        order by T0.ACTIVITY_DATE) = 1 then 1 else 0 end most_initial,
    case when row_number() over (partition by T0.MEMBERNUMBER, T0.ACTIVITYTYPE
        order by T0.ACTIVITY_DATE desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end most_recent
FROM DLA_EXTRACT_FINAL T0
```

Then you can use case statements to label as INITIAL if most_intial = 1, MR if most_recent = 1, or BETWEEN if both are 0.